# What is (a mod n) mod n?

Tags: real-analysis, modular-arithmetic

I have an equation such as

**(a + b) mod n** which is nothing but **(a mod n + b mod n) mod n** according to [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/582719/prove-a-b-mod-n-a-mod-n-b-mod-n-mod-n).

Now, I know that **b mod n** is 0 which results in **(a mod n) mod n**.

Is this equivalent to **a mod n** itself? If so, is there any way to prove it?

Comment: So you want to prove $(a+0)\pmod n=a\pmod n?$

Comment: You can see that $(a \bmod{n})\bmod{n}$ must be equivalent to $a\bmod{n}$. This is obvious because $a \bmod{n} \in [0,n-1]$ and so the second $\operatorname{mod}$ cannot have an effect. I hope this helps?

Comment: No. b is not equal to 0. **b mod n** is equal to zero.

Comment: @Shaktal Okay, so is it a given statement that the second mod has no effect? Can I take that as an axiom?

Comment: @SrinidhiS No, it's not an axiom. It follows _from_ the axioms (at least, it does if your axioms are somewhat reasonable), and is therefore a theorem.

Comment: @Arthur Thanks for the clarification.

Comment: That being said, to me, mod means something else. To me, it's not an operation you do to a number, so $a\mod n$ doesn't mean anything. I see it as a clarification of $\equiv$. So I write $a+b\equiv c$, and then, since $\equiv$ may mean different things in different contexts, I add a $\pmod n$ at the end to show what $\equiv$ means. So in total, I would write$$a+b\equiv c\pmod n$$and not$$a+b\mod n=c\mod n.$$ It changes a bit how you think about modular arithmetic, and in my opinion, it makes life a bit easier, since questions like yours here doesn't even appear (modding twice just isn't done).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can see that $(a \bmod{n})\bmod{n}$ must be equivalent to $a\bmod{n}$. This is obvious because $a \bmod{n} \in [0,n-1]$ and so the second $\operatorname{mod}$ cannot have an effect.

Moreover, if we consider what the $\operatorname{mod}$ operation does, then it makes sense that if $b\mod{n} = 0$ then we would expect $$a+b\equiv a\pmod{n}$$